# Is there a venv-specific equivalent of virtualenvwrapper's 'postactivate'

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

After starting my virtualenv, I would like to run a script that depends on some specifics of the environment (e.g. bash completions for some tools installed there). Is there a way to do this on a per-venv basis — effectively a local version of `postactivate`?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU `postactivate` is sourced at `workon` time. You don't automatically activate a virtualenv, you source `bin/activate` so you can add your code at the end of the `bin/activate` script.

To emulate `predeactivate` edit the same `bin/activate` script, function `deactivate`.

Comment: So (I think this is where I was mistaken) there's also a `postactivate` location to the virtualenv, that I can make executable and customize? That would do the trick, right?

Comment: There is only `bin/activate` but you can emulate `postactivate` with it.